# Symfony: generating slug url in my article url instead of news id

Tags: routes, doctrine, symfony, slug

I would like to have an url like this one:

```
www.mysite.com/my-super-blog-post
```

Instead of this one:

```
www.mysite.com/7
```

Where '7' is the id property of my News object.

When I see at the Symfony documentation I think I need to use this line of code:

```
$this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Is it right ? What I do not understand is where do I need to use that line of code ? In my NewsController.php file ?

Or maybe you can give me a link to read about a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Edit I use Symfony 3.2

Ok I've found the solution by my self. Here it is what I did.

Firstly read this from the symfony doc. Use ConvertParamater It is really easy to implement http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter

After you have implemented it:

Install StofDoctrineExtensionBundle

in composer.json

"require": {
  "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1"
}

Don't forget to update the appKernel.php file

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
  return array(
    // …
    new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
    // …
  );
}
```

Then I configure the config.yml file:

```
# app/config/config.yml

# Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle configuration
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
```

Then I add a slug property to my News Entity:

```
private $slug;
```

Then I update my News.orm.yml file
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 255
        unique: false
        gedmo:
            slug:
                separator: _
                style: camel
                fields:
                    - title

Then I do

```
doctrine:generate:entites myBundle:News
```

And also    `doctrine:schema:update --force

This created a slug field in my News table. Because this field may not be null, I have manually entered some value so each row of my News table has a valid slug

Then in my NewsController I use this line of code:

```
$this->generateUrl('myroute_news_show_one_by_id', array('slug' => $news->getSlug()), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

        return $this->render('MyBundle:News:single_post.html.twig', [
                    'news' => $news,
                    'tags' => $arrTagNames
        ]);`
```

And in my Twig template I create link like to show one news:

```
<a href="{{ path('myroute_show_one_by_id', {'slug': news.slug}) }}">{{news.title}}</a>
```

I hope this could help someone else

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using this old post as a reference for adding slugs to URLs, this functionality is baked into Symfony 4.  This post [Symfony 4 routing from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667830/symfony-4-routing-from-db) shows how to do it simply using

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
/**
 * @Route("/page/{slug}")
 * @ParamConverter("page")
 */
public function showAction(Page $page)
{
}
```

It's working beautifully in my test project.  Hope this helps someone!